# typeof self in an interface key

Tags: typescript, types

I have an interface that i wish it looked like this:

```js
export interface ProviderProps {
  resources: typeof ProviderProps["resources"];
}
```

So whatever object i give to resources, it would make the types off of it.
Let's say for example i gave it a resources object that looks like this:

```js
{
 key1: "this is the first key",
 key2: "this is the second key",
}
```

the type would looks like this:

```js
{
 key1: string,
 key2: string,
}
```

**Edit: a bit more context**:
I want to use this in React, exactly the context api, basicaly i have this context setup:

```js
interface UseLocaleModeProps {
  resources: Record<string, any>;
}
const LocaleModeContext = createContext<UseLocaleModeProps>({
  resources: {},
});
export const useLocaleMode = () => useContext(LocaleModeContext);
```

And when i setup the provider like this:

```js
<LocaleModeContext.Provider
  value={{
    resources: someResources,
  }}
>
  {children}
</LocaleModeContext.Provider>
```

I want the `resources`, to have the type of someResources automatically.

**Edit 2: Add a reproducible example:**

Here is a reproducible example in codesandbox, with comments:
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-usecontext-example-forked-0j4qg

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you’re trying to do exactly?  I don’t see how `resource` or `resources` relates to `key1` or  `key2`.  It would be helpful if you could provide a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE.

Comment: Is it a typo that you are typing property `resources` (plural) off of property `resource` (singular)?  I think what you are asking for is a "generic" `export interface ProviderProps<T> { resources: T }` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: That was only a typo, i edited it.

Comment: I added a bit more context.

Comment: Seeing your edit this is going to be tricky because the the value of a `Context` cannot be generic.  Meaning you cannot have multiple `Provider`s of the same context with differing value types.  Are there multiple `LocaleModeContext.Provider` components in your app or just one?  Is `someResources` a constant or is a mutable value that depends on state?

Comment: I'm trying to cobble together an actual [mcve] to see what you're talking about. Look [here](https://tsplay.dev/9Wv7Bw), for example. *Where* would you like `resources` to be the narrower type?  Note that this may well be inextricably linked with the typings for React.  If it turns out that the answer looks like "you need to rewrite all of [React's typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d498b7c4836191389b758296021f23e500f1fb07/types/react/index.d.ts#L333-L390) to allow for more generic-ness", you really should add a `react` tag s to get the right eyes on it.

Comment: I added an example in codesanbox with comments, i hope it answers both questions.
@LindaPaiste The provider will be only used once, in the global App file for example.

Comment: Type of an operational object can be obtained with typeof at execution time. It makes no sense in trying to set static definition of dynamic object type.

Comment: If it is coming from a json file and/or generated from some constant then you can use typeof to get the type of a variable dynamically ONCE.  If the value is changing during the runtime of your App, by you inserting keys in response to actions, then we have a problem.  Your provider must have a single fixed type.  It cannot change type during the lifecycle of the component.  Is that what you are trying to do?  If so, you need a vague type such as Record that can support any keys.

Comment: Yeah that's what i tried to do, i realised it's probably not possible.
What i'm gonna do instead, is to just provide the type explicitly using typeof.